# Check if array of object is not empty

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm a newbiw in Codeigniter and i so desperate facing this problem. So, I just made a simple application with CI. When I want to check an array of object (in this case array of $kunj->DIAG), I get an error notice.
Here's some appearance of my view:

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="tablescroll" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow" role="row">
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Nama</th>
      <?php if(!empty($kunj->DIAG)){ echo "<th>ICD</th>"; } ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <?php if(!empty($kunj)) print_r(count($kunj));
      if(!empty($kunj)){
        $no = 0;
      foreach ($kunj as $i): ?>
    <tr align='center'>
      <td><?php $no++; echo $no; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $i->NAMA; ?></td>
      <?php if(!empty($i->DIAG)){ echo "<td>".$i->DIAG."</td>"; } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
function kunjunganpx(){
    $this->load->model('simrs/diagnosa_model');

    $cari = array(
            'icd' => $this->input->post('icd'),
            'asr' => $this->input->post('asuransi'),
            'tgl_strt' => $this->input->post('tgl_strt'),
            'tgl_end' => $this->input->post('tgl_end'),
            'stat' => $this->input->post('px_stat'),
            'urut' => $this->input->post('urut'),
            'opsi' => $this->input->post('opsi'));

    $data['kunj'] = $this->diagnosa_model->get_kunjungan_list($cari);

    $this->load->view('kunjunganpx_view',$data);
}
```

And this is notice I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: simrs/kunjunganpx_view.php
```

From googling some site, I realize that array of object can not checked with `empty()`. But I desperately want to know how to fix this, since I generate my query result in object. 
All I wanna know is how to 'hide' the hardprint of ICD when there is no value in $kunj->DIAG. And show it if the variable has some values. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

As request from a member I attach the `var_dump($data);` result here:

```
array(1)    { ["kunj"]=> array(2) 
            { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (20) 
                {   ["NAMA"]=> string(13) "SUPRIYANTO BP" 
                    ["DIAG"]=> string(5) "D48.0" } 
              [1]=> object(stdClass)#22 (20) 
                {   ["NAMA"]=> string(13) "SUPRIYANTO BP" 
                    ["DIAG"]=> string(5) "C44.9" }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: `array of object` -> `$kunj["DIAG"]`, also how do you want to check if an object is empty?! The only thing would be if it isset

Comment: Check it with `isset()` instead of empty.

Comment: Can you show your controller code as its possible you are not passing this into your view

Comment: @Rizier123 I've try it with `isset()` but still not give result that I expected. Actually the notice have dissapear, but the ICD hardprint still missing altough $kunj->DIAG has values.

Comment: my comment above also notify for @Daniel comment

Comment: @psikoplak Edit your question, write update or something like this and show your current code

Comment: your request have just I include in update @MikeMiller

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($data);` before passing to the view and post the result?

Comment: Or, following @MikeMiller, do `echo "<pre>";print_r($kunj);echo "</pre>";` in the view. We need to know if anything is there and what it looks like.

Comment: ok @Daniel i hope  my update can represent the answer of your question. Now what should i do?

Comment: I am more used to using print_r, but I see an array and then objects. With $kunj as an array I would say you can access it with `$kunj[0]->DIAG`. Try to echo out that in the view before all the rest and see if you get your data.

Comment: absolutely agree with you @Daniel but the other problem is when index '0' is NULL, the script won't get to work. What i realy need is whether the DIAG is contain any value (not null) on any index, the script will executed. Any suggestion?

Comment: @psikoplak - I worked something out for you. Based on the fact that $kunj is an array and assuming that it is parsed in the view as an array by CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ... Based on the fact that `$kunj=array()` this is what I came up with.
`empty()` is not going to work, because the object has the property or not. If it has the property, then you want to parse the extra column.

You will need to test if the property DIAG exists in the object.

```
 if (property_exists($kunj[0], "DIAG"))
```

After that you can test if `$kunj` is empty, just like you are doing. In the foreach loop you will again have to test on the property before parsing the extra table cell. If that property is present, you will not have to test for empty. 
I have also changed some of your logic. It all results to this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="tablescroll" role="grid">
<thead>
    <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow" role="row">
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Nama</th>
      <?php
        if (property_exists($kunj[0], "DIAG")) {
            echo "<th>ICD</th>";
        }
      ?>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">

<?php if(!empty($kunj)){ foreach ($kunj as $k => $i): ?>

    <tr align='center'>
      <td><?php echo ++$k; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $i -> NAMA; ?></td>
       <?php
        if (property_exists($kunj[0], "DIAG")) {
            echo "<td>{$i->DIAG}</td>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach;  } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

codepad example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/3Jxi7k

Answer (score 0):

`if($kunj->DIAG != ''){ echo "<th>ICD</th>"; } ?>`
I think this will fix it, since some times
as i have seen, or understod, u dont get *null* values, but *empty* in thos vars.

Answer (score 0):

Could try this:

```
if (is_object($kunj) && !empty($kunj->DIAG)) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: actually this is still not work for me. the notice have just gone, but the result still doesn't meet my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem and **is_null** is the solution

try this :

```
    if(!is_null($kunj->DIAG)){echo "<th>ICD</th>";}
```